# JSF injected bean doesn't work with Primefaces tree

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, dependency-injection, primefaces, managed-bean

I have a managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BeanA implements Serializable {
    private TreeNode tree;

... }
```

and I want to inject it into

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BeanB extends Serializable {

   @ManagedProperty(value="#{beanA}")
   private BeanA injectedBean;

... getters and setters for injectedBean
}
```

but nothing happens when I try to reference properties of BeanA through BeanB on a page. Specifically, I am attempting top reuse functionality of BeanA (the data model for a primefaces tree) on a page that is backed by BeanB. No errors/stack traces result either. No tree is output on the screen but the tree is output on a page that makes direct use of BeanA.

Comment: Seems to be similar problem as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513374/injected-session-scoped-bean-in-view-scoped-bean-duplicating).  never seemed to be solved

Answer (score 0):

Put the annotation on a setter for Bean A rather than the member:

```
@ManagedProperty
public void setInjectedBean(BeanA beanA) {
   this.beanA = beanA;
}
```

Alternatively, use @Inject instead of @ManagedProperty